# Wildcard and type pameter bounds in java

Tags: java, bounded-wildcard, unbounded-wildcard

Consider this case:

```
class A {}

class B<T extends A, E extends T> {
    B<?, A> b;
    B<?, ? extends A> b2;
}
```

As I understand type bounds, in this case effective upper bounds of both `T` and `E` is `class A`. So the question: why javac doesn't accept class A as argument in declaration of field `b`, but accepts `wildcard` `? extends A` in declaration of field `b2`?

Comment: I use jdk 1.8.0 161

Comment: Can you share your test code ?

Comment: @xtratic I'm using JDK 11 and Intellij says `Type parameter 'Test.A' is not within its bound; should extend '?'`. If it compiles for you, then it could potentially be a bug in Intellij.

Comment: Ideone says: error: type argument A is not within bounds of type-variable E worked ok in local (eclipse, jdk1.8.0_171)

Comment: I have updated jdk to latest 1.8.0_191. And I get the same problem I described above.

Comment: As @Jacob G. says, I suspect it's a bug that this isn't a compile error for Eclipse JDT compiler (Eclipse 4.9.0 for me). I think this is a valid compile error, I'll try to explain why in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following classes:

```
class A {}
class C extends A {}
class B<T extends A, E extends T> {}
```

Think of it like this:

`E extends T extends A`
With `B<?,A>` then `T -> ?` and `E -> A`
`A extends ? extends A`
Where the `?` could be any subclass of `A`, let's say `C`.
`A extends C extends A` is clearly invalid.
So that's why it's a compile error.

---

### Note for Eclipse users:

Eclipse 4.9.0 compiler disagreed with javac 8u and Intellij and did not emit a compile error for the generic arguments in `B<?,A>`. I assume this is a bug in the Eclipse compiler but I have not consulted the JLS to confirm this.

```
class B<T extends A, E extends T> {
    B<?, A> b; // <-- Eclipse does NOT emit a compile error
    B<?, ? extends A> b2;
}
```

This assumed bug has been reported [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543081).

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is incorrect. You are missing the point of 'wildcard'-s. They are used for unknown property declaration. For `B<?, E> b` the `E` must extend the `T` and the `T` must extend the `A` but you said that the first generic type is `?` which is unknown! So you said that an unknown parameter must be extend `T` and so `A`. It is incorrect.

Relationship you created is like `E -> T -> A`. After that you declared as a 1. generic type `? -> E -> T -> A` and 2. generic type as `A -> E -> T -> ?`. So ? must extends ? and A must extends E vs.. It is confusing and unknown for compiler...

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration of field `b`, type `T` can be anything that extends `A`. In turn `E` must extend `T` however you are supplying type `A` for `T`. `A` will not be a subclass of something that is the subclass of `A`.